# Alternatives to $\backslash$

Tags: lyx, macros, verbatim

### Background

Instead of marking up the text with bold or emphasis, I read (and agree) that it is better to define a command, or environment, that describes the content. Then apply text formatting later.

### Problem

In LyX, it is trivial to highlight and make bold a Windows directory name. For example

**C:\apache-tomcat\webapps\**

Many such paths exist in the document I am writing. What I would like to do is create a new layout/style called `filename` that describes the content:<sup>1</sup>

```
\filename{C:\apache-tomcat\webapps\}
```

But `\` is the escape character. This means that the backslash must be transformed:

```
\filename{C:$\backslash$apache-tomcat$\backslash$webapps$\backslash$}
```

The `filename` command is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\filename}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

### Question

Is there another way to define the `filename` command that does not mandate the use of `$\backslash$` everywhere; rather keep using the literal `\` character? Something like:

```
\newcommand{\filename}[1]{\textbf{\verbatim{#1}}}
```

(I want to temporarily disable the special meaning of backslash.)

Thank you!

---

<sup>1</sup> What I really want to do is define my own styles/layouts in LyX while using the KOMA Script v2 class. However, the documentation on this aspect has insufficient detail for me to extend the class. That way I can simply highlight the text and apply the style, rather than resorting to LaTeX and ERT within LyX.

Comment: As an aside, rather than using `$\backslash$` you can use `\textbackslash` to get a backslash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the `\path` macro from the `url` package. Alternatively, you can make your own macro that behaves that way using `\DeclareUrlCommand`. For example, `\path` is (basically) defined as follows.

```
\DeclareUrlCommand\path{\urlstyle{tt}}
```

Of course, if you want bold, then you should use `bf` instead of `tt`.