# Expand directory names using nested macro definitions

Tags: expansion, urls, paths

### Background

Would like to use values from macros that reference other macros (n-levels deep) and apply their values to the `\path` command.

### Problem

(Scenario A) The following works:

```
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand*{\filename}[1]{\expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand*{\filephpdemo}{index.php}

\path{c:\programs\Apache\htdocs\}\filename{\filephpdemo}
```

Result:

```
c:\programs\Apache\htdocs\index.php
```

(Scenario B) This fails:

```
\newcommand*{\dirname}[1]{\expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand*{\dirhomeapachehttp}{c:\programs\Apache\}
\newcommand*{\dirhomeapachehttpdocs}{\dirhomeapachehttp\docs\}

\dirname{\dirhomeapachehttpdocs}\filename{\filephpdemo}
```

Actual result is an error:

```
 Missing }.
```

(Scenario C) This fails:

```
\newcommand*{\dirhomeapachehttp}{c:\programs\Apache\}
\newcommand*{\dirhomeapachehttpdocs}{c:\programs\Apache\hdtocs}
```

Actual result:

```
c:\programs \Apache \htdocs index.php
```

### Question

How can the `\path` command be used to expand and use the value of `\dirhomeapachehttpdocs` from Scenario B?

### Related

- [Alternatives to $\backslash$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/alternatives-to-backslash)
- [Using \nameref within \path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/using-nameref-within-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `\` means something to TeX. When you write

```
\newcommand*\dirhomeapachehttp{c:\programs\Apache}
```

(note I omitted the trailing slash), you're telling TeX that `\dirhomeapachehttp` is a macro that expands to 4 tokens: the two character tokens `c` and `:` and two control sequence tokens `\programs` and `\Apache`. This is not what you want.

One possibility is to make a new command that lets you define a macro that expands to the directory. I wrote such a command (see below), but it occurred to me that the `url` package already has such a command:

```
\urldef\dirhomeapachehttp\path{c:\programs\Apache\}
```

Now your Scenario B becomes

```
\dirhomeapachehttp\filename{\filephpdemo}
```

Just in case you were curious, here's what I came up with for a similar macro to the `\urldef`

```
{
\catcode`\^0
\catcode`\\12
^gdef^dirsep{\}
}
\newcommand*\defpath[2]{%
        \edef#1{\detokenize{#2}\dirsep}%
}
```

You use it like this.

```
\defpath\dirhomeapachehttp{c:\programs\Apache}
```

This you can use with your `\dirname` macro.

**Edit:**
This question is starting to a feel a little bit like a moving target. Note that as per your edit, what you want is for `\` to sometimes mean one thing (sometimes you want macro expansion) and sometimes you want it to be a directory separator.  I think probably the right thing to do here is to use `\urldef` to define the various path components and then, if you really need to stuff them together into a single macro, use `\newcommand` where the replacement text is made up of the various components.

Something like the following.

```
\urldef\dirhomeapachehttp\path{c:\programs\Apache\}
\urldef\dirdocs\path{docs\}
\newcommand*\dirhomeapachehttpdocs{\dirhomeapachehttp\dirdocs}
\dirhomeapachehttpdocs\path{index.php}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated Scenario B, but I think what you have given me is sufficient for me to make it work. Part of the problem was that I have dozens of directories and I was looking to use the `\path` macro once. I suppose it doesn't much matter: the important part is that the directory names are written only once.

Comment: @Dave: See the Edit for comments.

Comment: Thank you for the updated comments: they helped enormously.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if your question was educational i.e, learning about `\expandafter` or  related to a real issue you are working on. I have assumed the latter and provide below a different approach in solving the issue. I normally try to avoid `expandafter`, if possible and try to simplify the code.

I have defined a `\basepath` macro, which would normally need to be set once. You can then use the command `\fullpath` to typeset a full path URI by only providing a filename.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\gdef\basepath{\path{c:\programs\Apache\hdtocs}}
\def\afilename#1{\path{\ #1}}

%% examples
%
\basepath\afilename{index.php}

\basepath\afilename{category.php}

%% Defining a fullpath
%
\def\fullpath#1{\basepath\afilename{#1}}

%% Example fullpath
\fullpath{another.php}
\end{document}
```