# How to capture a colon in a macro?

Tags: programming, babel

I am trying to capture punctuation marks and I have a number of macros, two of which are shown in the minimal below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\def\isColon#1{%
\ifx:#1
    colon!
\else
   Not a colon!
\fi}

\def\isPeriod#1{%
\ifx.#1
   Period!
\else
   Not a period!
\fi}

\begin{document}
\isColon:

\isPeriod.
\end{document}
```

If the `babel` language is changed to `[french,english]` the colon is not captured, as babel makes it active. What modifications are required to the `isColon` macro to work in both cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `\if`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\def\isColon#1{%
\if:\noexpand#1%
    colon!
\else
   Not a colon!
\fi}

\def\isPeriod#1{%
\if.\noexpand#1%
   Period!
\else
   Not a period!
\fi}

\begin{document}
\isColon:

\isPeriod.
\end{document}
```

Another alternative would be `\pdfstrcmp`, but that is probably overkill here.

Comment: Note: The TeX `\if` test is used much less often than `\ifx`, but as it compares two _character_ codes it is idea here. The `\pdfstrcmp` primitive, available in pdfTeX, XeTeX (as `\strcmp`) and in LuaTeX (using a small piece of Lua) does a general character-based comparison, and is therefore useful in cases where you have two strings and want to ignore category codes.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\shorthandon{:}
\def\isColon#1{%
  \ifx:#1
    colon!
  \else
     Not a colon!
  \fi}%

\def\isPeriod#1{%
\ifx.#1
   Period!
\else
   Not a period!
\fi}

\begin{document}
\isColon: \isColon;

\isPeriod.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is not expandable: while this was not requested in the question, I think it's often useful to do it if possible.

Comment: @Joseph: true, I changed the code

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that outside of the macro, `:` is a macro expanding to `\active@prefix :\normal@char:` , but inside the macro, `:` is just the character `:`.  I believe this is because Babel registers the catcode changes with `\AtBeginDocument`; moving the macro definition after `\begin{document}` works just fine.  I also found that simply changing `\ifx` to `\if` worked fine without moving the macro definition.  But I think the cleanest solution (though a slightly specific one) is probably to change `:`'s catcode to active for the *definition* of `\isColon`:

```
\catcode`\:=\active
\def\isColon#1{%
\ifx:#1
    colon!
\else
   Not a colon!
\fi}
\catcode`\:=12
```

---

**Edit:** In case `:` has its catcode changed by something else, you ought to use this version instead:

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\:=\active
  \gdef\isColon#1{%
    \ifx:#1
      colon!%
    \else
      Not a colon!%
    \fi}
\endgroup
```

This resets the catcode of `:` to whatever it was before, not simply to `12`.

Comment: @Antal: you are taking an incompatibility risk here when reverting `:` to catcode `12`: maybe its catcode was changed by some other package. For these cases, I believe that it is better to put `\begingroup` before the catcode change, and `\endgroup` instead of reverting the catcode. Then we also need to change `\def` by `\gdef`.

Comment: You're definitely right.  I try to remember to do that, but not always with success.

Comment: @Bruno,@Antal: you can also do the same without a catcode change  and without a `\gdef` thanks to a lccode trick: \begingroup\lccode\`\~=\`\:\lowercase{\endgroup\def\isColon#1{\ifx~#1 colon!\else Not a colon!\fi}}

Comment: @Philippe: I've never seen that before—how does it work?

Comment: @Antal: with the `\lccode` change, `\lowercase` replaces `~` with `:` but doesn't change the catcode, so you obtain a `:` with catcode 13. More details in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7359

Comment: @Philippe: "Not a colon!" will also be lowercased, though, so we need to add \lccode`\N=`\N before \lowercase.

Comment: @Bruno: yes, or you could put "Not a colon!" and "colon!" each inside a macro to avoid any hassle of this kind.