# LaTeX3 - Expand nested argument

Tags: expl3, expansion, latex3

**MWE**:

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {a}
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\mathbf{\l_tmpa_tl}}
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {b}
\(\l_tmpb_tl\)
```

The code snippet above actually produce `\(\mathbf{b}\)`. What I want to achieve is to produce `\(\mathbf{a}\)`, i.e., expand the `l_tmpa_tl` in the second line. However `l_tmpa_tl` is nested inside the `\mathbf` command and I do not know how to expand it. I tried

```
\exp_args:NNx \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\exp_args:Nx \mathbf{\l_tmpa_tl}}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \exp_not:N \mathbf { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } }
```

---

Your approach doesn't work for two reasons.  First, you can't nest `x`-type expansion, because `x`-expansion itself does not work inside `x` (or `e`) type expansion.  Second, is that `\exp_args:N...` does not stop the function from expanding, so even after `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \exp_args:Ne \mathbf { ... } }` (`e`-type expansion *does* work inside `x`- and `e`-type expansion), `\mathbf` would be expanded.  What you need here is `\exp_not:N` to prevent expansion.  Then, you can also replace `\exp_args:NNx \tl_set:Nn` by the simpler `\tl_set:Nx`, and as a matter of safety, prevent further expansion of `\l_tmpa_tl` by using `\exp_not:V` (`\exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl` will expand the value of `\l_tmpa_tl`, and prevent further expansion).

Answer (score 3):

In general case, just define auxiliary functions to do the work.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {a}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tmp:n #1 {  % when this is executed, it will set \l_tmpb_tl to the desired result
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\mathbf{#1}}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tmp:n {V}
\__tmp:V \l_tmpa_tl
```

Alternatively, since the operation is expandable you can do this...

```
\cs_set:Npn \__tmp:n #1 {  % this expands to **exp_not** of the desired result
    \exp_not:n {\mathbf{#1}}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tmp:n {V}
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\__tmp:V \l_tmpa_tl}
```

... which is usually more flexible/convenient.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is quite hard to figure out by yourself & read only interface3.pdf, I add this one to my idiom list post.

Comment: The exp_not thing is also a expl3 kind-of idiom...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, in case you wish to get more familiar with expl3's various expansion-types:

If you want to rely on the statement of interface3.pdf that token-list-variables can be retrieved directly, i.e., without needing a `\tl_use:N`, within a single expansion-step, you can combine `o`-expansion with `\exp_after:wN`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {a}
\tl_set:No \l_tmpb_tl {\exp_after:wN \mathbf \exp_after:wN {\l_tmpa_tl}}
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {b}
%\(\l_tmpb_tl\)
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
%
% Neither \documenclass nor \begin{document} was used, so let's end the
% latex-run with the sledgehammer:
%
\stop
```

If you don't like `\exp_after:wN`, you can trigger `f`-expansion and have that stopped by an explicit space-token `~` or by an implicit space-token `\exp_stop_f:` which gets discarded by the `f`-expansion-mechanism when stopping:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {a}
\tl_set:Nf \l_tmpb_tl {\exp_args:NnV \use:n {\exp_stop_f: \mathbf} \l_tmpa_tl}
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {b}
%\(\l_tmpb_tl\)
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
%
% Neither \documenclass nor \begin{document} was used, so let's end the
% latex-run with the sledgehammer:
%
\stop
```

If you want to make sure that things might still work out when expl3-policy reagarding direct usage of token-list-variables changes, you can combine `o`-expansion, `\exp:w`/`\exp_end:`-expansion and `\exp_args:NnV`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {a}
\tl_set:No \l_tmpb_tl {\exp:w \exp_args:NnV \use:n {\exp_end: \mathbf} \l_tmpa_tl}
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {b}
%\(\l_tmpb_tl\)
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
%
% Neither \documenclass nor \begin{document} was used, so let's end the
% latex-run with the sledgehammer:
%
\stop
```

Comment: Small (not really important) nitpicks: a more idiomatic way to end an `f` expansion is `\exp_stop_f:` (an implicit space token) rather than `~`.  Also, `N` and `V` arguments don't need braces around them (doesn't hurt either)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for pointing out opportunities for improvement. I have just edited my answer to take these things to heed. :-)