# How to get listings to print only the header of a Matlab file?

Tags: listings, matlab

How to extract the first line of a simple matlab file *and* the following lines just after that begin with the character `%` ? The number of lines to extract is unknown. Then I want to use `listingsutf8` to display the code extracted.

Example of matlab file :

```matlab
function myfunction(args)
% Comments
% about the function
% with an unknown number of lines
command1(); % another comment
command2();
% another comment
command3();
end
```

lines to extract :

```matlab
function myfunction(args)
% Comments
% about the function
% with an unknown number of lines
```

Comment: Are you using a language predefined by `listings`, such as `Matlab`?

Comment: yes it's true it is matlab syntax ;) but I use `mcode` package (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package)

Comment: Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: interesting, thx :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of relatively arcane `listings` internal macros; no need to write to an external file.  For convenience, I've defined a new boolean key called `onlyheader`. If that key is set, any output after the first contiguous block of comment lines (i.e. the function header) is dropped.

**Edit**: This feature has been implemented in [version 0.2 of `matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier/wiki/Home) via a key called `mlonlyheader`.

[image: mlpr output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% --- write to file ---
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{code.txt}
function myfunction(args)
%MYFUNCTION One-line description goes here
% Comments
% about the function
% with an unknown number of lines
[ 2 3 4 ]
command1(); % another comment
command2();
% another comment
command3();
end
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstset{style = Matlab-editor}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting
  [caption  = {\texttt{mlonlyheader=false}}]
  {code.txt}

\lstinputlisting
[
  caption    = {\texttt{mlonlyheader=true}},
  mlonlyheader = true,
]{code.txt}

\end{document}
```

### Using only `listings`

[image: listings output]

```
\documentclass{article}

% --- write to file ---
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{code.txt}
function myfunction(args)
%MYFUNCTION One-line description goes here
% Comments
% about the function
% with an unknown number of lines
[ 2 3 4 ]
command1(); % another comment
command2();
% another comment
command3();
end
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
% We define a new boolean key for convenience
\lst@Key{onlyheader}{false}[t]{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifonlyheader}

% We'll use this switch to keep track of where we are
\newif\iffirstnoncommentline

% --- Careful! the following modifications are global ---
% (i.e. will apply to all listings)
\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}{\global\firstnoncommentlinetrue}
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\dropOutput}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\dropOutput}

% helper macro
\newcommand\dropOutput
{%
  \lst@ifonlyheader%
    \ifnum\lst@lineno>1%  
      \lst@ifLmode%
      \else
        \iffirstnoncommentline%
          \lst@EnterMode\lst@Pmode{}%
          \lst@BeginDropOutput\lst@Pmode%
        \fi
        \global\firstnoncommentlinefalse%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
  language = Matlab,
  frame    = single,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting
  [caption  = {\texttt{onlyheader=false}}]
  {code.txt}

\lstinputlisting
[
  caption    = {\texttt{onlyheader=true}},
  onlyheader = true,
]{code.txt}

\lstinputlisting
[
  caption    = {\texttt{onlyheader=true}},
  onlyheader = true,
]{code.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @badboy I hadn't anticipated such a need for my `matlab-prettifier` package. Can you tell me why you want to extract the header? Documentation purposes?

Comment: yes it's for documentation :)

Comment: oh yeah, great ;) In my case it is documentation of functions I coded so I know what I write in the 'header' but it's not the case for built-in functions ...

Answer (score 3):

File handling in this manner is not something that is necessarily best handled all-in-one with TeX.  It would be much better to do the processing outside of TeX, and then use the result inside TeX.

This method (abstracted from [How can I save shell output to a variable in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70854/how-can-i-save-shell-output-to-a-variable-in-latex?rq=1)) is somewhat of a compromise.  It uses the `write18` TeX primitive to run a shell command, which saves the output you seek into a temporary file.  This temporary file is then used as the listing source.

I am still working out if/how this can be done with all TeX primitives, not using the shell command workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}    
\begin{document}

% Execute a sed script to identify the lines that are desired
% from the top of your code file (note that the % sign has to be 
% escaped in this line, due to LaTeX interpreting it differently)
% This command was developed with sed on Mac OSX 10.9
\immediate\write18{sed -ne '1 h; 2,/^[^\%]/ {x;p;}' myfunction.txt > '\jobname.temp'}
                % Sed command:
                % 1 h; Take first line, hold in buffer
                % 2,/^[^%]/ Lines 2 through the next line that doesn't
                %     begin with a %
                % ... {x;p;}  Hold current line in buffer (swap with previous)
                %             and then print out previously held line
                % This results in line 1 + next continuous lines beginning with % printed

% Set language -- looked like MATLAB was a prime candidate given the syntax
\lstset{language=Matlab}

% Print out original function
Contents of \verb!myfunction.txt!:
\lstinputlisting{myfunction.txt}

% Print out newly created file
Dynamic header of \verb!myfunction.txt!:
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.temp}

% Clean up temporary file
\immediate\write18{rm -f -- '\jobname.temp'}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: Result of code example]

Comment: thx for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The `filecontents` package is used only to create the files to be input.

The code fetches the asked for lines. They may be manipulated directly, or with the `listings` package. For this I again write the lines to a file and input them: there surely is something easier and more elegant, but it turns out I am completely unfamiliar with `listings`. [The update adds `\lstset{language=Matlab}`]

Notice that no shell-escape nor external tools are needed in this approach. The macro `\GetHeaderAndDisplayWithListing` does the job in one go. I guess the listing itself is customizable via `\lstset` but I have reached only page 3 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}% only to create files for this example
\begin{filecontents*}{badboysamplefile.txt}
function myfunction(args)
% Comments
% about the function
% with an unknown number of lines
command1(); % another comment
command2();
% another comment
command3();
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{badboyotherfile.txt}
function myfunction(args)
% 1 Comments
% 2 about the function
% 3 with an unknown number of lines
% 4 Comments
% 5 about the function
% 6 with an unknown number of lines
% 7 comments
% 1 Comments
% 2 about the function
% 3 with an unknown number of lines
% 4 Comments
% 5 about the function
% 6 with an unknown number of lines
% 7 comments
command1(); % another comment
command2();
% another comment
command3();
end
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter

\def\ExtractLines #1{%
 \newread\badboy 
 \openin\badboy #1\relax 
 \edef\ELrestore{\endlinechar\the\endlinechar\relax\catcode`\%=14 }%
 \endlinechar -1
 \ExtractLines@
 \ELrestore
 %\show\ELrestore
}%

\def\ExtractLines@ {%
    \ifeof\badboy 
       \def\ExtractedLines{}\closein\badboy
    \else
      \read\badboy to \ExtractedLines
      \edef\ExtractedLines{\detokenize\expandafter{\ExtractedLines}}%
      \catcode`\% 12
      \ExtractLines@@
    \fi
}

\def\ELSEP{\par}
\def\ELgetfirst #1#2\ELgetfirst {\def\ELFirst{#1}}

\catcode`\% 12
\catcode`! 14
\def\ExtractLines@@ {!
  \ifeof\badboy \closein\badboy\else
    \read\badboy to \Extract@OneLine
    \edef\Extract@@OneLine{\detokenize\expandafter{\Extract@OneLine}}!
    \expandafter\ELgetfirst\Extract@@OneLine.\ELgetfirst
    \if %\ELFirst 
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \ExtractedLines\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           {\expandafter\ExtractedLines\expandafter\ELSEP\Extract@@OneLine}!
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \ExtractLines@@
    \else
       \closein\badboy
    \fi
  \fi
}
\catcode`% 14
\catcode`\! 12
\makeatother

\newcommand\GetHeaderAndDisplayWithListing [1]{%
   \def\ELSEP {^^J}%
   \ExtractLines {#1}%
   \newwrite\badboy
   \immediate\openout\badboy badboy-extracted.temp\relax
   \immediate\write\badboy {\ExtractedLines}%
   \immediate\closeout\badboy\relax
   \lstinputlisting {badboy-extracted.temp}%
   \def\ELSEP {\par}% just in case one wants to use \ExtractLines
   % and the produced \ExtractedLines directly
}

\begin{document}
% added in update:
\lstset{language=Matlab}

First file with \verb|listings|:\medskip

\GetHeaderAndDisplayWithListing {badboysamplefile.txt}

% \ExtractLines {badboysamplefile.txt}%
%  \texttt{\ExtractedLines}
% \bigskip

And the second file with \verb|listings|:\medskip

% \ExtractLines {badboyotherfile.txt}%
% \texttt{\ExtractedLines}

\GetHeaderAndDisplayWithListing {badboyotherfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

The output (now using `\lstset{language=Matlab}`):

[image: extracted lines with listings Matlab]

The output of the initial answer (which did not even need package `listings`), using the now commented out `\ExtractLines` and `\texttt{\ExtractedLines}`:

[image: extract lines]

Comment: Are you able to use the result of \ExtractedLines as the input to a listings environment?

Comment: I am novice with `listings`. But writing to a file and re-inputing with `\lstinputlisting` should definitely work, at least. (one would use something else than `\par` then as line separator).

Comment: @jfbu thx for your answer