# Custom line-breaks in minted environment

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I'm using the minted package for my code listings.
I'd like to customize the line-breaks instead of using the *breaklines* option that does the line-breaking automatically. Unfortunately I haven't found a proper solution yet. I also experimented with escapeinside without any success. :(

So in my case I have the following minted environment:

```
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg, breaklines]{bash}  
docker run -it --net rc --name hubot -e ROCKETCHAT_URL=rocketchat.rc:3000 -e ROCKETCHAT_ROOM='' -e LISTEN_ON_ALL_PUBLIC=true -e ROCKETCHAT_USER=<username> -e ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=<password> -e ROCKETCHAT_AUTH=password -e BOT_NAME=bot -e EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-pugme,hubot-help,hubot-diagnostics rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat
\end{minted}
```

And I'd like to set line-breaks manually... maybe by adding a *?* or some other token at the position I want to have the line break. Is this possible or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `breakafter=`?

Comment: can you not simply disable automatic breaks and manually add the line breaks to your source? (that is, use the default behaviour)

Comment: `breakafter=?` would work of course. But it would print the additional _?_ also. I need a token that makes the line break but that won't get printed :)

Comment: If I would add line breaks to the source code it would be semantically incorrect. The whole line is one command. I cannot cut it somewhere. If I would do so the line numbering would also be incorrect.

Comment: Bash command lines can be broken at a backslash trailing the line. This would be semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

The example below should give you what you want, or at least a good place to start. This uses `breaklines` to enable line breaking, but disables breaking at spaces by using `showspaces` to enable a custom space-replacement character, and then setting that to a non-breaking space. Currently, `?` becomes `\linebreak`. Depending on how you use this, it might be worth looking into `\allowbreak`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
  \catcode`?\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\?\lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\linebreak}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines, showspaces, space=~]{bash}  
docker run -it --net rc --name hubot ?-e ROCKETCHAT_URL=rocketchat.rc:3000 ?-e ROCKETCHAT_ROOM='' ?-e LISTEN_ON_ALL_PUBLIC=true -e ROCKETCHAT_USER=<username> ?-e ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=<password> ?-e ROCKETCHAT_AUTH=password ?-e BOT_NAME=bot ?-e EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-pugme,hubot-help,hubot-diagnostics ?rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just found this, seems to be the only way to force a line break in bash code… am I correct in that conclusion? Everything else I've tried fails because the bash lexer considers backslashes as strings. How much of that block is necessary if I *just* want to force line breaks at `?` characters?

Comment: @DustinWheeler You would need all of this if you want to specify break locations with `?` rather than allowing breaks at spaces or elsewhere.

Comment: I haven't used `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` before… I don't quite understand how this works. I _think_ that it's taking the question mark and turning it into the lowercase definition for a tilde… but why the `\lowercase{` _inside_ the group? Is there a resource to read on groups and the use of `\lccode`?

Comment: @DustinWheeler Maybe look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7372/10742, or search through some of the other questions/answers that use this approach

Comment: Will do, thanks!