# Display ".\integrate blah" in monospaced font (like \texttt and \verb)

Tags: fonts, verbatim, typewriter

I'm trying to display the following:

.\integrate blah

in a monospaced font.

For everything else I've wanted to put in a monospace font, `\texttt` or `\verb` has worked fine, but it doesn't with this. I've worked out that I need to escape the `\` in the text, but replacing it with `\\` gives a newline.

What should I use to escape the \ in LaTeX?

Comment: `\verb+\integrate+` works OK.

Comment: Is that trying to display an integration sign? I'm trying to display the actual text "integrate".

Comment: No. `\verb+\integrate+` will display "\integrate" in a monospaced font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\verb` to display a backslash in monospaced font; the following example shows another option to display a backslash in monospaced font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\verb+\+

\texttt{\symbol{92}}

\verb+\integrate+

\texttt{\symbol{92}integrate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `\textbackslash` to produce a backslash. To get it monospaced, you should use T1 font encoding which is [recommendable anyway](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc), otherwise it's not a true typewriter backslash.

You might also have a look at answers to these questions:

- [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)
- [When should one use \verb!! and when \texttt{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt)
- [Alternatives to $\backslash$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/alternatives-to-backslash) which shows the `\path` macro of the `url` package for such a purpose

Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\verb|.\integrate|

\texttt{.\textbackslash integrate}

\texttt{.\char`\\integrate}

\path{.\integrate}
\end{document}
```

[image: backslash screenshot]

Comment: but `\textbackslash` will not produce a backslash in monospaced font.

Comment: @Gonzalo: it produces a monospaced backslash in T1 encoding, which is [very recommendable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc).  You're right, with the default (OT1) encoding the backslash would be in another font. I will add that restriction to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\cs{\ttfamily.\textbackslash}
\begin{document}

\cs{integrate}

\end{document}
```